# Pointer to array as a whole

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, matrix

I have 4 arrays that I need to combine into 1 by adding all the corresponding cells. So I would add up Cell 1,1 (row 1, column 1) of all 4 matrices and put that into Cell 1,1 of the resultant matrix.

Well the 4 matrices are coming from another program and instead of writing an adder function that takes 4 matrices as the argument, I just had 1 vector. So my function looks like this:

```
void combine_matrix(vector<int*> all_arrays) {
    vector<int> cell_values; //Vector that stores the value of a particular cell of each matrix

    for (int i = 0; i<all_arrays[0].size(); i++)
}
```

`vector<int*> all_arrays` is a vector of pointers that points to the 4 arrays. This way, the matrices can be of any size (all 4 have to be the same dimensions though) and the function would still work.

Basicaly I want a vector of pointers pointing to the array as a whole so I can use the `size()` function but all the examples I've seen are only giving me pointers to the actual elements in the matrix. Any idea on how to do what I need? Thanks

Comment: Pointers don't know the size of the list they point to. Just use a vector of vectors instead and make life easier for yourself. The alternative is to add a parameter for the lengths or use boundary markers (a special number which cannot appear in real input, e.g. INT_MAX. Such a number may not be available though)

Comment: @Dave but the inputs are 4 2D arrays, there's no changing that. So can I have a vector of arrays?

Comment: You need to add 2 arguments which pass the dimensions to the function (since as you say, all 4 must have the same size). The more OO way is to define a new object which stores the data and dimensions (or use an existing matrix library).

Comment: @Dave quick question, if I have a vector of pointers to arrays as shown above, how would I access individual elements of a particular array. So if I wanted to access the 2nd array I know I put `all_arrays[1]` but then how do I access the element in the 3rd row and 5th column?

Comment: @Richard: there is very little support for multi dimensional arrays in C or C++.  You have `int mda[12][20][30];`, but as you noticed this decays quickly to a pointer to the first element.  In C++, you can have `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` but that's not easy to work with.  You can make one yourself or have a look at boost multi_array: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `Matrix` class that contains the pointer to array and the size and other things you might need to work with, and even better, make a `CombinedMatrix` class that contains `vector<Matrix>`